# Converting to Serializable object

Tags: java

this may be a stupid question but I wanted to convert a 2 dimensional string array into a serializable object in java. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: It is evident from the error message you posted below that your problem has nothing to do with Serialization whatsoever. -1.

Comment: A String, String[] and String[][] are all serializable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Arrays are already Serializable. So is String. You don't need anything more.

Here is a complete example :

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Arrays;

/**
 * @author Colin Hebert
 */
public class Serial {

    public static void main(String[] args)
            throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        PipedOutputStream pos = new PipedOutputStream();
        PipedInputStream pis = new PipedInputStream(pos);

        String[][] strings = new String[][]{{"q","w","e"},{"a","s","d"},{"z",
                "x","c"}};

        serialize(strings, pos);

        String[][] strings2 = deserialize(pis);

        System.out.println(Arrays.deepEquals(strings, strings2));
    }

    public static String[][] deserialize(InputStream is)
            throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(is);
        return (String[][]) ois.readObject();
    }

    public static void serialize(String[][] array, OutputStream os)
            throws IOException {
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(os);

        oos.writeObject(array);
        oos.flush();
    }
}
```

---

**Resources:**

- [This code on ideone](http://ideone.com/lGLy5)
- [oracle.com - Object Serialization Stream Protocol](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/platform/serialization/spec/protocol.html)

Comment: Thanks, the reason I asked this question was because im making a web service and the entry point takes a string[][] as a parameter but when I test it using the web services explore i keep getting this exception

Comment: soapenv:Fault>
  <faultcode>soapenv:Server.userException</faultcode> 
  <faultstring>org.xml.sax.SAXException: Found character data inside an array element while deserializing</faultstring> 
- <detail>
  <ns1:hostname xmlns:ns1="http://xml.apache.org/axis/">Name</ns1:hostname> 
  </detail>
  </soapenv:Fault>

Comment: @user78087 That fault has nothing to do with Serializable.

Comment: Im sorry im new at this and assumed it might be because of that.

Comment: @user78087, as this post could be somehow useful to someone someday, I recommend you to simply create another one explaining your actual problem with code example and the exact error, and just let this post as is.

Answer (score 0):

```
        ObjectOutputStream stream = null;
    try {
        stream = new ObjectOutputStream(out);
        String strings[][] = {
                {"a", "b", "c"},
                {"1", "2", "3"},
        };
        stream.writeObject(strings);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();  //$REVIEW$ To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }
```

Here goes the answer. Arrays are by default serializable. Just write it to ObjectOutputStream like another serializable object